# Return last matched row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
 id | qty_from | qty_to | p_id | price 
--------------------------------------
 1  |    1     |   10   |  4   | 1000  
--------------------------------------
 2  |    11    |   20   |  4   | 2000  
--------------------------------------
 3  |    1     |   10   |  5   | 500   
--------------------------------------
 4  |    11    |   20   |  5   | 1000  
--------------------------------------
 5  |    1     |   10   |  6   | 1000  
--------------------------------------
 6  |    10    |   15   |  6   | 2000
```

And i tried to get rows by `qty_from` AND `qty_to` AND `p_id` using below code

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE p_id IN ('4', '5', '6') AND qty_from <= 8 AND qty_to >= 8
```

It returns 1st, 3rd and 5th rows.
And when i use this code, it return only 1st and 3rd rows.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE p_id IN ('4', '5', '6') AND qty_from <= 16 AND qty_to >= 16
```

I want to return 6th row too. because it's the biggest qty in `p_id = 6`
How can i achieve this?

Comment: But with row id = 6, the the qty_to = 15 which does not satisfy your condition `qty_to >= 6`. Maybe you need to use OR instead of AND?

Comment: it don't display biggest your largest qty in p_id = 16 is less than 16

Comment: @Beginner I know. i want some code to returns the biggest qty if there is no match

Comment: Join with `SELECT p_id, MAX(qty_to) FROM table GROUP BY p_id`, and use that if there's no row from the first query.

Comment: So, you wants 1st, 3nd, 5th and 6th records in result ?

Comment: I don't really get your goal, but one question. Is your goal is to get the row which has largest qty_to in each p_id? please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Meloman, 1st, 3rd, 6th. not 5th

Comment: @Beginner, Only when WHERE statement is not true. The second query is true for `p_id = 4 AND p_id = 5` but it's false when `p_id = 6`

Comment: Ok, so what's the conditions to have 1st, 3rd and 6th !? If we check your table, it's difficult with normal conditions to get that.

in 6th the qty_to is not the biggest ! qty_to >= 16 so 15 doesn't match

Comment: wait you said if it's true? but row 6 doesn't meet the condition

Comment: @WithoutBrain1994 I see

Comment: @Meloman, It's the biggest in `p_id = 6`

Comment: @Beginner, No i said not true

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I think we understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve this.
Thanks to @Meloman for giving me the clue.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE p_id IN ('4', '5', '6') AND ((qty_from <= 16 AND qty_to >= 16) OR (qty_to, p_id) IN (SELECT dd.qty_to, dd.p_id FROM table dd INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(qty_to) AS mm, p_id FROM table GROUP BY p_id) ddd ON dd.p_id = ddd.p_id AND dd.qty_to = ddd.mm WHERE dd.p_id IN ('4', '5', '6'))) GROUP BY p_id
```

I test this multiple times and i think it's the answer

Answer (score 1):

After discuss here is what you need *(first and not tested solution)* :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *, MAX(qty_to) as max_qty_to FROM `limit`) T
WHERE p_id IN ('4', '5', '6') 
AND ( ( qty_from <= 16 AND qty_to >= 16 ) OR qty_to = T.max_qty_to )
```

Comment: Invalid use of group function

Comment: THis is the mysql error returned ? we don't use grouping !

Comment: Max is a grouping function, using it without GROUP BY gives error.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your where condition to achieve your desired result. The updated query will be -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE p_id IN ('4', '5', '6') AND qty_from <= 10 AND qty_to >= 8
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t3.*
FROM `table` t1
LEFT JOIN `table` t2 ON t2.id=IFNULL(
    (SELECT id FROM `table` t3 
     WHERE t3.p_id=t1.p_id AND 16 BETWEEN t3.qty_from AND t3.qty_to 
     ORDER BY qty_to DESC LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT id FROM `table` t4 
     WHERE t4.p_id=t1.p_id 
     ORDER BY qty_to DESC LIMIT 1))
WHERE t1.p_id IN ('4', '5', '6')
```

Basically, first a table with the given p_ids is fetched and then joined with the rows of the most desired ids per p_id (if 16 is not in range of qty_from and qty_to, the one with the biggest qty_to is taken).

One flaw: If multiple rows match the range condition, only the one with the biggest qty_to is selected, so there is only one result per p_id. I hope that's sufficient for you!